# How to make a copy of a database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, clone

I can't seem to find any SQL that will clone one database in SQL Server within the same server.

Let's say I have a database called `MyDB`. I simply want to make a copy of `MyDB` to `MyDb2`. I thought that this would work:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDB TO MyDB2;
```

But I get this error when I try to execute it:

> Backup device 'DbTestBack' does not exist. To view existing backup devices, use the sys.backup_devices catalog view. To create a new backup device use either sp_addumpdevice or SQL Server Management Studio.

Does anyone know what the best way to do this is? I want an exact duplicate of the original including security permissions.

Comment: (1) **BACKUP** to a file on the server, (2) **RESTORE** that `.bak` to the new `MyDB2` database, (3) you're done!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18866321/1578713

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, database snapshots may work http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx

Comment: I understand the backup and restore option. What I really want is a simple solution and it would seem this would be possible.  If not, then I will end up going this route.

Comment: @marc_s Do you have some sample code to do this?  While your list of actions makes it seem simple, but it does not address the issue of how to deal with the new data/log file location?  I am writing a script that will know nothing of the environment it is running on and I don't know SQL well enough to know how to read the file locaiton from the DB and modify it for the new DB name.

Comment: The [SQL Server Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) has **extensive** documentation on **all** T-SQL commands with tons of samples.....

Comment: This runs on specific version only, please check your version is not express or with all privileages.

Answer (score 8):

A simple way is taking a back up copy of current DB and restoring it.
You Can do this in single step with a simple script

```
backup database MyDB 
to disk='D:\MyDB.bak';


restore database MyDB2
from disk='D:\MyDB.bak'
WITH move 'MyDB_Data' to  'D:\MyDB2_Data.mdf',
move 'MyDB_log' to  'D:\MyDB2_Data.ldf';
GO
```

**Note**: I made an assumption on your current data file and log file name (`MyDB_Data`, `MyDB_log`), you need to check them and make correct

Answer (score 0):

[DBAtools](https://dbatools.io) is your friend here.

Use [Copy-DbaDatabase](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaDatabase)

ie.

```
Copy-DbaDatabase -Source SRV1 -Destination SRV1 -Database myDB -BackupRestore -SharedPath \\<<your temporary server location such as c:\temp>>
```