# Linux: Make mongodb to use a different data folder (dbPath)

Tags: mongodb

Using CentOS 7.
Used yum install mongodb-org

If I change the dbPath in /etc/mongod.conf it is not working when I start the mongod with systemctl start mongod.service. However if I start like mongod --dbpath /new/folder it is working fine.

In the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) it is given that

> The Linux package init scripts do not expect storage.dbPath to change
>   from the defaults. If you use the Linux packages and change
>   storage.dbPath, you will have to use your own init scripts and disable
>   the built-in scripts.

How to change the default init scripts?

I have gone through 
[Changing MongoDB data store directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961145/changing-mongodb-data-store-directory)
[Moving MongoDB's data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758816/moving-mongodbs-data-folder)
[how to set mongod --dbpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448268/how-to-set-mongod-dbpath)

Comment: Try using `sudo systemctl reload mongod` . It will reload the config once again

Comment: @Vim, Yes I tried stopping and starting the mongod as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove your service, restart your computer, then create a new service with mongod option `--dbpath` : `systemctl enable mongod.service`. It should work !